# Как получить ip адреса устройств, подключенных к WiFi?

Tags: java, android, ip, wifi

Возможно ли средствами API android или встроенными/сторонними java-инструментами получить список ip (неважно, в каком виде) адресов этих устройств на устройстве, которое тоже подключено к данной сети?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае - никак. Дело в том, что некоторые wifi бывают настроены на режим "изоляции". В этом режиме роутер блокирует попытки подключения внутри сети.

Но в общем случае всегда можно попытаться выполнить команду [arp](http://www.flattermann.net/2011/02/android-howto-find-the-hardware-mac-address-of-a-remote-host/), но она покажет список "известных устройств".

В любом случае обычно в сети не более 256 устройств, и можно просто пропинговать (но и тут не все обязаны отвечать).

Comment: В дополнение очень хочется сказать про Network Discovery: https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery  
Там как раз есть и arp-проверки, и ping-проверки.  
Рекомендую ознакомиться с исходниками.